# Why is my html page vertically scrollable in such a short portion?

Tags: html, css

I am a newbie in html mobile programming. For some strange reasons, my webpage is behaving in a stange way.

As the screenshot below shows, I have a vertical scrollbar displayed for the first quarter of my page. I don't understand why it is shown.

[image]

I have googled for quite a few hours (without knowing exactly what to search exactly) and I am not quite sure whether the problem is linked to my html page or its linked css code.

Any idea what's going wrong or what I am doing wrong here? Thanks a lot for your help.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>Domoos mobile </title> 
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="600">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/> 
    <!--Using jQuery and jQuery UI for display effects--> 
    <script src="js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="jquery-1.12.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script> 
    <!--Using the hamburger menu display code--> 
    <script src="scripts/hamburger.js"></script> 
    <!--Using Media Queries, if the viewport is smaller than 700px use another stylesheet--> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/hamburger.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle_hamburger.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/date_time.js"></script>
    <script>
        // Global variables
        var AutoScript = false;
        var ValueCheck = -1;
        var ControleurUpdate = "";
        var ThermostatManualUpdate = false;
    </script>
</head> 
<body>
<!--This wrapping container is used to get the width of the whole content--> 
    <div id="container"> 
    <!--The Hamburger Button in the Header--> 
    <header>
        <div id="hamburger">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        </div>
    </header> 
    <!--The mobile navigation Markup hidden via css--> 
    <nav> 
    <ul> 
    <!--<li><a href="#"><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">menuitem 1</a></li> -->
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menuitem 6</a></li>
    </ul> 
    </nav> 
    <!--The Layer that will be layed over the content 
    so that the content is unclickable while menu is shown-->   
    <div id="contentLayer"></div> 
    <!--The content of the site--> 
    <div id="content">      
    <div class="tag_domoos_title">
        <p>Domoos mobile</p>
    </div>
        <div class="domoos_logo">
        <img src="assets/icons/logo_Domoos_lab.png" alt="" style="width:75px;height:54px;">
    </div>
    <div id="tag_sunrise_sunset">
        <p><img src="assets/icons/sun_icon.png" alt="" width="14" height="14">&#8593; 06:25 &#8595; 20:33</p>
    </div>

    </div>
    </div>
</body> 
</html> 

#tag_domoos_title{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 110%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 101px;
    color:black;
    z-index:10;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#date{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 101px;
    color:blue;
}
#time{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 103px;
    left: 101px;
    color:blue;
}

#tag_sunrise_sunset{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_condition{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 130px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#tag_weather_temperature{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 148px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 900;
}

#current_weather_conditions{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 90%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 168px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_icon {
  position: relative;
}

#meteo_icon img{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 80px;
}

#meteo_forecast{
    font-family:Arial;  
    font-size: 100%;
    float:left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height:434px;
    width:870px;
    top:200px;
    position: absolute;
}

#meteo_forecast_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;    
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;    
    font-weight: 600;
}

#meteo_forecast_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
    font-weight: 600;   
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 260px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 330px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_temperature_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 400px;
    left: 220px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day1{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 280px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day2{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 350px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}

#meteo_forecast_condition_day3{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 80%;
    text-align: left;
    position: absolute;
    top: 420px;
    left: 11px;
    color:black;
}


#domoos_logo{
position: relative; 
}

#domoos_logo img{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 10px;
}

#lorem{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size: 100%;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    top: 700px;
    left: 10px;
    color:black;
}
```

Comment: You don't have any more content, that's why. Just add some content.

Comment: is your css style really that way in your html file?

Comment: actually, the css is a separate file called 'mystyle_hamburger.css'

Comment: @Johannes: what exactly do you mean by adding more content ? What if I simply have no more content to add... sorry for the silly question but I am a newbie. Thanks for your indulgence.

Comment: The problem is that everything is positioned absolutely. Absolute position takes elements out of the normal flow calculation. Because of this, the body tag is not the correct height. Absolute positioning should be a completely last resort. Take out the absolute positioning and make the site without it. The scrollbar will go away.

Comment: A website with just a logo and nothing else makes no sense - if you don't have any content yet, add some blindtext and placeholder images to see how it's displayed. Also, as @rockerest writes, don't use all that absolute positioning. But still, if there isn't anything to see, how do you what to judge how it's giong to be displayed once you add some text and images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this probably because you are telling the browser that this div is 434px height!

what you should do is always have the height set to "auto" like this :

```
#meteo_forecast{
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Add more content, also if you're a newbie have a look at http://getbootstrap.com/. It has all the CSS taken care of and you'll learn a thing or two about how to build a site. First example that comes to mind is that you keep reiterating that the font family to be used is Arial for each DIV, you could simply add the font family to the body and the other divs would inherit  the font that you want.